# how to enable apache tomcat 8.5 after stopping

Tags: tomcat

My one of the application is deployed using apache tomcat 8.5 .And it was working fine.Suddenly Apache tomcat 8.5 is showing disabled in the services and hence I am not able to start its services.What could be the possible reasons of apache tomcat 8.5 got disable all of a sudden?

And how can I start it again?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some application you are using has disabled the Apache service from the Windows Services.

You can type : **Services** in the run command of your windows installation.
Locate Apache Service.
Right click the service and select Properties. Set Startup type: Manual or Automatic.
Then on the top left Start the service

Comment: I did the same thing Set Start type  as Automatic and apply it.When I open it  again I find it is showing disabled again.

Comment: Is there any other process running on the same http port (usually 80 or 8080) that tomcat is trying to run?